# How to parse nested complex JSON data from API in Dart Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, object, model

I couldn't parse the position and the 84, 86 objects inside it

```
 {
        "id": 5679,
        "position": {
            "84": {
                "price": "880.00",
                "price_value": 880,
                "id": 84,
                "item_id": 55,
                "product": {
                    "id": 55,
                    "price_value": "880.00",
                    "product": {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "Алюкобонд 3мм 1,22х2,44 (зеленый, красный, белый)",
                        "slug": "alyukobond-3mm-122kh244-zelenyy-krasnyy-belyy",
                    },
                    "main_price": {
                        "id": 31,
                        "item_id": 55,
                        "item_type": "Lovata\\Shopaholic\\Models\\Offer",
                        "price": "880.00",
                        "old_price": "1100.00",
                    },
                    "price_link": []
                },
                "item_type": "Lovata\\Shopaholic\\Models\\Offer",
                "quantity": 1,
                "max_quantity": 20,
                "weight": 0,
                "property": "0.00"
            },
            "86": {
                "price": "1 000.00",
                "price_value": 1000,
                "product": {
                    "id": 56,
                
                    "name": "Алюкабонд",
                  
                    "price": "1 000.00",
                    "price_value": "1000.00",
                    "old_price": "0.00",
              
                    "price_list": [],
                    "product": {
                        "id": 15,
                        "active": 1,
                        "name": "Алюкобонд бронза 3мм 1,22х2,44",
                        "slug": "alyukobond-bronza-3mm-122kh244",
                    },
                    "main_price": {
                        "id": 32,
                        "item_id": 56,
                        "item_type": "Lovata\\Shopaholic\\Models\\Offer",
                        "price": "1000.00",
                        "old_price": "0.00",
                        "price_type_id": null,
                        "created_at": "2022-11-18 10:02:47",
                        "updated_at": "2022-11-18 10:02:47"
                    },
                    "price_link": []
                },
                "item_type": "Lovata\\Shopaholic\\Models\\Offer",
                "quantity": 1,
                "max_quantity": 5,
                "weight": 0,
                "property": "0.00"
            },
        "shipping_price": {
            "price": "0.00",
            "price_value": 0,
        },
        "position_total_price": {
            "price": "2 980.00",
            "price_value": 2980,
           
        },
        "total_price": {
            "price": "2 980.00",
            "price_value": 2980,
            
        },
        "quantity": 3,
        "total_quantity": 3,
        "weight": 0,
        "payment_method_id": null,
        "shipping_type_id": null,
        "user_data": null,
        "shipping_address": null,
        "billing_address": null,
        "property": null
    }
```

Comment: Guys please note that position object has another two object inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json data using [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) instead of making custom data modals.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply decode the JSON result (`rawJson`) which you receive on the API call using `json.decode()` or `jsonDecode()` and store the result to a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Keep in mind to `import 'dart:convert';` before you can use these functions.

The code will look something like:
`Map<String, dynamic> resMap = jsonDecode(rawJson)`

Now you can access data normally as you want from `resMap` given you know the schema/structure of the JSON which you parsed since the Map will have the same structure.

If you want to parse the API response in the background of your app and not overload your main thread, you can create separate isolate to do that too.
The flutter team have a good documentation regarding that which you can check out ([Parse JSON in the background](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing)
). Creating a separate isolate is the proper way to go if you don't want to overwork your main thread and let it concentrate on the GUI only. This results in way better performance more so if the app is big.